# Sending integer output to another activity

Tags: eclipse, android-activity

Suppose, I have added 2 integers in an activity. I want to do arithmetical operations and want to show the output in another activity by clicking a button. What should I do?

N.B. : I want to take the values in Numbers(Decimal) so that I can take values dynamically and added a button also.

Answer (score 0):

You can add key into bundle object and send this bundle with intent.

Code while sending intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SendMessage.class);
intent.putExtra("result", 10);
intent.startActivity();
```

Code while receiving intent

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String receivedValue;

if (extras != null) {
    receivedValue= extras.getString("result");
}
```